# Google Sheets Script to count cells with color with several criteria

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a google sheets table, I use a script that allows me to count the cells in color in a column that displays dates as values. Each date over 11 days is colored in red, and my script works very well.

In another column, I indicate the name of each salesman.
What I would like is to be able to count the number of red cells that belong to each salesman.

The date column is column "G" and the salesman column is column "F" (In my script it doesn't matter because I indicate in which column to count).

My Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BFd57xpFOJMOAjuRaiO6_cLCMMxQKDwi_TB6dOCDb9A/edit#gid=0

The formula for my script is:

```
=CompteCouleurs($G6:$G;C4)
```

"$G6:$G" is the range to count
"C4" is the sample of the color to search

My script is:

```
function SommeCouleurs(plage,couleur) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formule = activeRange.getFormula();
  
  
  var laplage = formule.match(/\((.*)\;/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(laplage);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var lacouleur = formule.match(/\;(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(lacouleur);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();
  
  var total = 0; 
  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
      total=total+(values[i][j]*1);
  return total;     

};


function CompteCouleurs(plage,couleur) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formule = activeRange.getFormula();
  
  
  var laplage = formule.match(/\((.*)\;/).pop();
  var range = activeSheet.getRange(laplage);
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();
  
  var lacouleur = formule.match(/\;(.*)\)/).pop();
  var colorCell = activeSheet.getRange(lacouleur);
  var color = colorCell.getBackground();
  
 var count = 0;

  
  for(var i=0;i<bg.length;i++)
    for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)
      if( bg[i][j] == color )
      count=count+1;
      return count;
};
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your sheet? Also, could you explain what is not working?

Comment: Link of my sheet just added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, expand your area to G and F `=CompteCouleurs($F6:$G;C4)`

Then as you only take column G into account, you can omit `for(var j=0;j<bg[0].length;j++)`

Therefore you can check color in G and salesman in F as follows `if( bg[i][1] == color && values[i][0] == salesman )`

If you want to include the salesman as parameter, you will have to change the regex as follows to retrieve each argument (args will be an array)

```
var args = formule.match(/\(.*\)/g)[0].match(/[A-Z0-9:]+/g)
```

I recommand also to add a dummy parameter (checkbox) to update the calculation

### Correction of your script:

```
function compteCouleursSi(plage, couleur, vendeur) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formule = activeRange.getFormula();

  // array of arguments
  var args = formule.match(/(?<=\().*(?=\))/g)[0].split(/[;|,]/)

  var laplage = args[0];
  if (laplage.includes('!')) {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(laplage.split('!')[0].replace(/'/g,'')).getRange(laplage.split('!')[1].trim());
  }else{
    var range = activeSheet.getRange(laplage);
  }
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var lacouleur = args[1];
  var color = activeSheet.getRange(lacouleur).getBackground();

  var salesman = args[2];
  var who = activeSheet.getRange(salesman).getValue()

  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < bg.length; i++)
    if (bg[i][1] == color && values[i][0] == who)
      total += 1;
  return total;

};

function sommeCouleursSi(plage, couleur, vendeur) {
  var activeRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSheet = activeRange.getSheet();
  var formule = activeRange.getFormula();

  // array of arguments
  var args = formule.match(/(?<=\().*(?=\))/g)[0].split(/[;|,]/)

  var laplage = args[0];
  if (laplage.includes('!')) {
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(laplage.split('!')[0].replace(/'/g,'')).getRange(laplage.split('!')[1].trim());
  }else{
    var range = activeSheet.getRange(laplage);
  }
  var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
  var values = range.getValues();

  var lacouleur = args[1];
  var color = activeSheet.getRange(lacouleur).getBackground();

  var salesman = args[2];
  var who = activeSheet.getRange(salesman).getValue()
  
  var total = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < bg.length; i++)
    if (bg[i][1] == color && values[i][0] == who)
      total += values[i][1];
  return total; 

};
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry in "F" column I have not color in cells it's Value( salesman name).

Comment: I would llike a formula like ; NB.SI(F:F;"name";CompteCouleurs($G6:$G;C4))

Comment: yes, I understand, and that doesn't change my proposal : 1st parameter = data (G and F), second parameter = color, third parameter = salesman

Comment: try my proposal, you will not be able to mix a custom formula with nb.si formula, because your costum formula doesn't return an array but a value.

Comment: Ok I will try now, but the script you wrote is for "SommeCouleurs"but I use "CompteCouleurs".

Comment: Link of my sheet just added

Comment: In my script I have 2 functions, first "SommeCouleurs" and second "CompteCouleurs". The first one adds the values in the colored cells and the second one counts the number of colored cells. And also this script is updated automatically if I change a value in the search range. That is possible to keep those 2 functions and only add the condition for the salesman?

Comment: I have an error: Erreur 
Exception: Range not found
compteCouleursSi @ Compter Cellule Colore Condition.gs:10

Comment: Erreur
Exception: Range not found (ligne 10).

Comment: désolé, corrigé et testé https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1M5-veICqZviaQs2eA8a29HQwoSMmv1rr6KxdO0BoJPA/copy

Comment: I have the same error. I think because I put the formula in another tab

Comment: sure! and at first your formula should give the same error either! it's why providing and example is usefull. You have to split the args by split('!') and take account of the sheet I will add this tomorrow

Comment: I have added the possibility that data is located in another tab.

Comment: Thank you Mike, all is working well now.